# Running out of memory and process killed during Cholesky decomposition with Dask

Tags: python, arrays, memory, dask

I'm trying to compute the cholesky decomposition of a matrix with 49152x49152 elements (around 19 Gb) in a laptop with only 16 Gb of RAM. I've seen that using dask it's possible to work with matrices that does not fit in memory, but running my code it always run out of memory (it does not matter if I change the number of chunks).

Here is where my code breaks:

M3 is a (49152, 49152) matrix, definite positive and non-singular.

```
M3 = da.rechunk(M3, chunks = (Chunks, Chunks))
chol_x2 = da.linalg.cholesky(M3, lower=True)
da.to_npy_stack("./Prueba_Nside_64", chol_x2)
old_name = "./Prueba_Nside_64/0.npy"
new_name = "./Prueba_Nside_64/Cholesky_Decomposition_Nside_64.npy"
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

I've tried different Chunks, always checking that each chunksize is less than 1Gb. I'm not sure if the problem is the cholesky decomposition or the .to_npy_stack function. Which function should I use to save the cholesky decomposition?

I've just realized the code breaks if I try to compute a single element from cholesky. How could I compute the cholesky in my own laptop? Or maybe it's not even possible?

Comment: Please show all your code, ideally boiled down (eg is the rename necessary to reproduce the error?) and as a full [mre]. With dask especially this is vital because the memory explosion could be caused by earlier tasks which have been scheduled but do not get executed until these lines require them.

Comment: +1 with @MichaelDelgado, debugging this will be really difficult without a MRE. Please try to give one with automatically arrays

Answer (score 2):

I did a few tests with my laptop also with 16GiB.

I reproduced out of memory error on workers with just this code:

```py
import dask
import dask.array as da

x = da.random.random((49152,49152))
x3 = da.tril(x, k = -1)
da.to_npy_stack("./Prueba_Nside_64", x3)
```

At first I thought this came from the `tril` function, but it is actually the `to_npy_stack` call that is causing issues.
Indeed, storing as Numpy stack requires chunking in only one axis, so it triggers some rechunking that fills Worker memory.

Just using another format (that can directly write the dask array chunks) did the trick for me:

```py
x3.to_zarr("./Prueba_zarr")
```